# How to create a directory users can't delete (but can delete files in it)?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, samba, directory

Is it possible to create a directory that ordinary users cannot delete, but they could create and delete files and subdirectories inside this directory? i.e. for

```
/share/permanent/
```

users could create files and directories both in `/share` and `/share/permanent` but cannot delete `/share/permanent` directory (nor `/share` directory either).

`/share` should be a samba-share so permissions maybe be set on `smb.conf` if not possible on file system?

Comment: chown `/share/permanent` to a user no one can access (e.g. root) and write protect `/share`

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario where the directory is /share/permanent/

```
    mkdir -p /share/permanent
    chmod 755 /share
    chmod 777 /share/permanent
    sudo chown -R root:root /share
```

This works because now deleting /share/permanent would be considered writing to share, which is only writable by root.  /share/permanent/ can be written to by and read by anyone.

If you want to make it so that people can only delete file that they own you can set the +t flag with chmod.